# Some directories don't have prop:directory in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

In Marklogic DB some of the directories don't have a prop:directory,how to fix this.
we have set directories creations are automatic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. By default MarkLogic sets directory creation to manual. To cause MarkLogic you have to set it to automatic, but you have to do so **before** loading of documents. You might need to reload data to observe those directory property fragments you are seeking.

Note of caution: setting directory creation to automatic slows down ingest because it needs to do more work, but it also causes contention, and documents getting written in the same path will both attempt to create such directory fragments. Keep in mind that these directory properties are only necessary for WEBDAV access. Directory queries work fine without them.

HTH!